# Regex to match two numbers but nothing else

Tags: regex, grep

Take the following contents of a file:

```
"52245"
"528"
"06156903"
"52246"
"530"
"00584709"
```

What pattern would match both 52245 and 52246 but nothing else?

Comment: You should edit and refine the question and say why "52245" and "52246" are "good" numbers (5-digit, beginning with 522, Iowa zip codes) and why the others aren't.

Comment: Regexes are based on patterns.  If you don't tell us what the pattern is, we can only guess and will probably be wrong. :)

Comment: I guess that leaves me out (Waverly, IA 50677)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something that can only match those two numbers and nothing else:

```
^\"5224[56]\"$
```

Now if you're looking for something a bit more general (for example, any number with 5 digits), you'll want something like

```
^\"\d{5}\"$
```

I'm assuming the quotation marks (`"`) are part of the file. If they aren't, omit the `\"` parts from the expression.

The particular grep expression you want is this:

```
grep -E "^\"[[:digit:]]{5}\"$" filename
```

or to take a suggestion from the comments:

```
grep -P "^\"\d{5}\"$" filename
```

I've tested both and they work on my machine!

Comment: Yes the quotation marks are part of the file. I am using grep like this:

grep ^\"\d{5}\"$ myfile

It returns nothing, I have also tried with -G and -E options

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: \d is a Perl style special character.  Try grep -P ^\"\d{5}\"$ .  I think there are other ways to match digits without -P and \d, but they're not worth it.

Comment: Take care to escape everything from your shell though. In bash, that means using single quotes around the regexp.

Comment: i'm not sure that the \d{} is correct...I use [[:digit:]]\{5\}..and you should put " around your expression (use grep with -e too).

Comment: I've included your suggestion into the answer, David Berger. Good tip. I didn't know about -P until now.

Answer (score 11):

```
^(52245|52246)$
```

You can use this.

Comment: Technically correct. I'm almost sure he's looking for something else, but wasn't specific about what.

Comment: @mmyers Oops, didn't see the "grep" tag.  I supplied a java regex where quoties would not be used.

Answer (score 7):

```
^"5224[56]"$

^"5224(5|6)"$

^"52{2}4[56]"$

^"(52245|52246)"$

...
```

You should base the regex you use on the semantic you want to express. If you are looking for two arbitrary numbers use `^"(52245|52246)"$`. If the numbers have any meaning - a type code or something like that - I would stick with `^"5224(5|6)"$`.